# How to find all instances of highlighted text in the active document and removes the highlight formatting with mark-up?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do you find all instances of the highlighted text in the active document and remove the highlight formatting with mark-up?

I found a macro in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.highlight. But I want it to remove the highlight formatting with mark-up. I tried to add " ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True" to turn on the Track Changes but in vain.

```
Sub A()
    Dim rngTemp As Range 
 
    Set rngTemp = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0) 
    With rngTemp.Find 
     .ClearFormatting 
     .Highlight = True 
     With .Replacement 
     .ClearFormatting 
     .Highlight = False 
     End With 
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, FindText:="", _ 
     ReplaceWith:="", Format:=True 
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Then I tried to record a Macro and edited it as follows:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Highlight = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Selection.Find.Execute
        
End Sub
```

The second one can only change highlighted text to no highlight with mark-up one by one. It is not convenient since I have at least 200 highlighted texts to decide whether they should be corrected in a document. How can I edit it to automatically select all highlighted text and then remove their highlights with mark-ups?

Comment: Did you try a search? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+%5Bms-word%5D+remove+highlight

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I didn't search for that. I just searched and can't find a version with Track Changes opened.

Comment: You can achieve what you want simply by turning on Track Changes and doing a Find and Replace, without using any code.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I know. But every workplace has its difficulties. Someone is extremely lazy that just wants to press a button to finish all the things.  That's why I came here to seek help from anyone who can figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub FindRemoveHighlighting()
    Dim findRange As Range: Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
    With findRange
        With .Find
            .Highlight = True
            .Text = ""
            .Format = True
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute() = True
            .HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh My god. Thank you so much for your help! Words are not enough to express my gratitude.